# about the nuance of the meaning of "embedded" in "an operation to remove glass that was embedded in his leg"

Tags: word-difference

Below is an example phrase from [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/embed).

> an operation to remove glass that was **embedded** in his leg

I am wondering what differences in meaning **embedded** makes in that phrase, compared to other alternative words like **stuck**, **inserted** or **got**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Each of the verbs you choose suggests something quite different.

Most commonly, especially as a result of explosions, people speak of objects becoming LODGED in people's flesh. These can be wooden splinters, glass shards or bits of metal.

**Embedded** suggests that the glass was firmly anchored in his leg and would be difficult to remove.

**Stuck** indicates that the glass could not easily be plucked out. It does not indicate how deeply it had penetrated.

**Inserted** signifies that someone had put the glass in his leg, which sounds unlikely.

And you can't write: **glass that was got in his leg** although you can turn it around and say that: **he had got glass (stuck) in his leg**. People sometimes talk like that informally although it's a very loose way of putting things.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. It is so helpful.:) But, would you also give an explanation for __an operation to remove glass that got in his leg__? Though, I appreciate your explanation about the fact that "glass that was got in something" is wrong.

Comment: @SmartHumanism **Glass that got *into* his leg** is a simple, almost childish way of speaking. It suggests that the glass intentionally worked its way into his leg. However it would be correct to say: *Glass that got lodged in his leg*, meaning *became lodged*.

Comment: I am very sorry to ask you this again, and to be seen to not trust your explanation completely. But I really appreciate your answer. Is there really no way to interpret **glass that got in his leg** other than **the glass intentionally worked its way**? Is there no possibility that the listener would take that as somehow condensed form?